# Istio virtual service not working for port other than 80 and 443

Tags: istio, istio-gateway

I am trying to set up `istio` virtual service along with the `gateway` but somehow it's not working.

Here is my gateway configuration

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: nginx-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        name: admin
        number: 9999
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - nginx.example.com
```

Virtual service

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: nginx-virtualservice
spec:
  gateways:
    - nginx-gateway
  hosts:
    - nginx.example.com
  http:
    - match:
        - port: 9999
      route:
        - destination:
            host: nginx
            port:
              number: 80
```

However it works only for port `80` and `443 but not for other ports.

Comment: The http port in namespace specific gateway should be mapped to istio ingress gateway service port.  when istio gets installed, ingress gateway ports are created for 80 and 443 by default.  if you want http port as 9999 then this has to be configured in istio ingressgateway service port.  Pls check kubectl get svc -n istio-system and edit ingress gateway svc.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, when you created the istio-ingressgateway, you used the default values, so only port 80 and 443 are opened.
Look at the ingressgateway service/deployment and open the port 9999, you can add it in the [operator](https://istio.io/v1.14/docs/reference/config/istio.operator.v1alpha1/#ServiceSpec).
Right now you have the Gateway listening to the port 9999 but probably the traffic can't go through it.